# The assembler did not show any output?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I want to show 'F' in screen .When I compiled my code , It did not have any problem but it did not show 'F'.
The compiler is:emu8086
The code is :

```
stseg segment
db 64 dup(?)
stseg ends

dtseg segment
dtseg ends

cdseg segment
main  proc far
assume cs:cdseg,ds:dtseg,ss:stseg
mov   ax,dtseg
mov   ds,ax
call  clear
call  color
call  moh
mov   ah,4ch
int   21h
main  endp

clear proc
mov  ax,0600h
mov  bh,07
mov  cx,0000
mov  dx,184fh
clear endp

color proc
mov   ah,0b
mov   bh,0
mov   bl,4
int   10h
color endp

moh  proc
mov cx,100
mov dx,30
back:mov ah,0ch
mov al,01
int 10h
inc cx
cmp cx,130
jnz back
mov cx,100
mov dx,50
loo: mov ah,0ch
mov al,01
int 10h
inc cx
cmp cx,130
jnz loo
mov cx,100
mov dx,30
joo: mov ah,0ch
mov al,01
int 10h
inc cx
cmp cx,50
jnz joo
cdseg  ends
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set videomode to graphics first as you are painting that F, e.g. int 10 with ah 0x00 and al 0x04  (selects 320x200 4 color graphics mode)

Comment: Maybe thats the intent of the clear-proc, but there is definitely missing an int?

Comment: should I write this command in cdsegment before calling functions?

Comment: I would just before the call to moh (which does the painting) do mov ah,0 mov al,4 int 10 (ok, each of this instructions has to go on a separate line)

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you should wait some time after painting the F? e.g. read a char from kbd after painting is done.

Comment: can you run this program with your compiler and see what happen? if it is possible for you if it is not possible, it is not important thank you for your helping.

Comment: Sorry, I can't. Just called back things I did 20 years ago. You are wellcome.